# mongodb aggregation from two different match dates

Tags: mongodb

I need to build an aggregation on collection A. 
some fields will be aggregated up to 5 min match , and others up to 1 hour match .
If I add step in the pipeline to match 5 min then I can't have the 1 hour to calc the other group.
How I can do that in the same query so I can have all the results built in one plcace .

Thanks in advance ...

Comment: Try adding a query as you've already tried it, and perhaps a sample set of documents - that makes it much easier to see what you're trying to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> have all the results built in one place

It's possible to do this, but it is rather complicated. It would be much easier to do this with two aggregations that both output their results into a new collection to hold those results. Then you still have your results in a single place without a complicated query.

If you really do want to do it with one query, here's a way you could do it:

1. Aggregate to the five minute level

   - Handle five minute data as you would if you were only querying for it
   - Start aggregating hour data
2. Aggregate to the hour level

   - Push five minute data into an array
   - Calculate hour aggregation

The documents this results in each represent an hour and have an array representing the data for each of the twelve five minute periods in that hour.

One thing you need to keep in mind is that some things, like averages, should be calculated *after* you're done aggregating the data. You can do this with an additional `$project` at the end.